# schedule a task with yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using YII framework for my website. I would like to schedule a task, as in, if a user has his/her birthday, then the scheduler will pop a birthday greeting for the particular day and remove it a day later? Has YII any inbuilt functionality to trigger such events? For Windows OS? Or is there any alternative to Cron jobs?

Comment: check this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-scheduler/

Comment: @SureshKamrushi It doesn't work for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule it as a cron job. That's the easiest way!!Write a console command in php to check the birthdays for the day and schedule this command as a daily cron job.Cron will execute daily and if der is any birthday the popup action will get executed.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: @DencyGB I have heard that cron jobs create a problem in windows OS. Is it true?

Comment: As far as i know,Cron is available on Unix, Linux and Mac servers. Windows servers use a 'Scheduled Task' to execute commands. My server is Linux and I am doing it with cron.